# Return encoded Page Title outside of a loop

Tags: php, encoding

This is for a sidebar "Email this page" button (so outside of a loop) It will appear on Pages, products and archive pages. I've got the URL returning ok but can't get the page title to appear. The Page Title has to be encoded (so the spaces need to be converted to %20, etc).

What I have so far:

```
<?php 
global $wp;
$url = home_url( $wp->request );
$page_title = get_the_title();
?>
<?php
echo '<p class="side-bar-buttons"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> ';
echo '<a href=mailto:?subject=CompanyName%20' . urlencode($page_title);
echo '&body=' . $url;
echo '>Email This Page</a></p>';
?>
```

It opens a new email with the "Company Name" in the subject but the page title won't appear. The URL is in the body as per the client's wishes.

Any idea how to get the page title? Wierd how the thing you think will be dumb simple are so complicated.

Comment: Because it's outside of the loop `get_the_title();` doesn't know which title to get; that'd be my guess here.  You have to pass the ID of the page title you want into it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:
Load wp_get_document_title(); into a variable.
Use 'rawurlencode' on the variable.
Also, apparently one can use a " , " to join to strings and not just " . "

````
global $wp;
$url = home_url( $wp->request );
$page_title = wp_get_document_title();
?>
<?php
echo '<p class="side-bar-buttons"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> ';
echo '<a href=mailto:?subject=' , rawurlencode($page_title);
echo '&body=' . $url;
echo '>Email This Page</a></p>';
?>```
````